# image array in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I'm trying to create an image array and save it into a variable called manosData.   I already tried this code

```
myFolder = 'C:\MATLAB\fotos';
filePattern = fullfile(myFolder, '*.jpg');
jpegFiles = dir(filePattern);

manosData = cell(1,numel(jpegFiles));

for k = 1:length(jpegFiles)
    baseFileName = jpegFiles(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(myFolder, baseFileName);
    fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
    imageArray64x64 = imread(fullFileName);
    imageArray64x64New = imresize(imageArray64x64, [64 64]);

       manosData{k} = imageArray64x64New;
end
```

%Save

But when i try to plot my 8 images, i just get a blank window. This is the code am using for that:

```
load manosData
for j=1:9
subplot(3,3,j)
end
```

Thanks, Cath.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
load manosData
for j=1:9
subplot(3,3,j)
image(manosData{j})
end
```

the command `subplot` just creates a subaxis to the current figure. You need to apply a plotting command, for example `image`, `plot`, or `line` to draw any content to the axes.

Comment: trying that i get just the last image. The code that creates the variable is rewriting, how can i make that code store all the 8 images and not just the last one.

Comment: Do you mean it just plots the last image? Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: it just plots the last image. But i need them all.

Comment: @CatherineDefrank this example works for me: `for j = 1:9
    subplot(3,3,j)
    imagesc(rand(20));
end` -- perhaps you can try and see if there is any difference to what you're getting now with your data?

Comment: What rand (20) does?, cuz when I try that I get 9 windows with color pixels. Do you have an idea about how to make an image matrix array that stores all my 8 images? Thanks

Comment: Which command do you give to save your data? (The line "%Save" in your original question).